# Kafka Kstream Json Join cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka and Kstreams. I am trying to perform a join two streams and push the output to a third stream. I have tried few days on various implementations and now stuck at this error.
 error and couldn't proceed. can someone please help?

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.JoinWindows;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Joined;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Properties;

@RestController
public class KafkaProcessingController {

    private KafkaStreams streamsInnerJoin;

    private Properties properties(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "stream-stream-inner-join");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        return  props;
    }

    private void streamsInnerJoinStart(StreamsBuilder builder){
        if (streamsInnerJoin != null) {
            streamsInnerJoin.close();
        }
        final Topology topology = builder.build();
        streamsInnerJoin = new KafkaStreams(topology, properties());
        streamsInnerJoin.start();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/startStreamStreamInnerJoin2/")
    public void startStreamStreamInnerJoin2() {

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, Item> leftSource = builder.stream("my-kafka-left-stream-topic"
                , Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new SchoolSerde() )        );
        KStream<String, Item> rightSource = builder.stream("my-kafka-right-stream-topic"
                , Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new SchoolSerde() ));
        KStream<String, Item> joined= leftSource
                .selectKey((key, value) -> value.getName() )
                .join(  rightSource
                            .selectKey((key, value) -> value.getName())
                                ,(value1, value2) -> {
                                    System.out.println("value2.getName() >> "+value1.getName()+ value2.getName());
                                    return value2;}
                        ,JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                        ,Joined.with(
                         Serdes.String(),
                         new SchoolSerde(),
                         new SchoolSerde()
                        )
                );
        joined.to("my-kafka-stream-stream-inner-join-out");
        streamsInnerJoinStart(builder);
    }

    public class SchoolSerde extends Serdes.WrapperSerde<Item> {
        public SchoolSerde () {
            super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Item.class));
        }
    }
}
```

This is what i have in kafka topics, it's same on both topics

```
CreateTime:1588414271850    1   {"id":1,"name":"nuwan","category":"home"}
```

This Item.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String category;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    @JsonCreator
    public Item(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("category") String category) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", category='" + category + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Final error

```
Exception in thread "stream-stream-inner-join-0816e64b-5e97-4ca1-bb08-5976d3506e33-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=2_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000006, topic=stream-stream-inner-join-KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000002-repartition, partition=0, offset=5, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: ex4.Item). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to the fact the incorrect `Serdes` are provided for the repartition caused by the `selectKey` operation.

Just for some context, anytime you change the key and perform a join or aggregation, Kafka Streams will automatically repartition the data to ensure the changed key is on the correct partition.

But, from what I can see, you are providing the correct `Serdes` for the repartition(s) in the `Joined` method.

```java
Joined.with(Serdes.String(),
            new SchoolSerde(),
            new SchoolSerde())
```

but for some reason, the default `Serdes` from the config is used instead.  Instead of a debugging session, you can try this as a workaround for each stream.

```java
leftSource.selectKey((key, value) -> value.getName() )
           .through("left-source-repartition", 
                    Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new SchoolSerde())
           .join(
            rightSource.selectKey((key, value) -> value.getName() )
                        .through("right-source-repartition", 
                                Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new SchoolSerde()),
.....
```

This workaround should get you going again. 
EDIT: I forgot to mention you'll need to create the topics for the `through` operation and the new topics will need to have

1. The same number of partitions each
2. At least the same number of partitions as the source topics ideally the same number.

What version of Kafka Streams are you using?

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @bbejeck I go through your suggestions and get back to you!
Kafka Stream version is 2.3.0